# Getting error while trying to get plular (resources not found exception: Plural resource ID $0x7f0e0001 quantity=1 item = one

Tags: android, kotlin

Updated code, keeping data class simple and using extensions to for getting description. Maybe would be useful for somebody:

```
@Keep
@Parcelize
data class Passengers(
    val adults: Int = 1,
    val teenage: Int,
    val children: Int,
    val infants: Int,
) : Parcelable
fun Passengers.getDescription(context: Context): String {
    val joinPassengers = StringJoiner(", ")
    if (adults > 0) joinPassengers.joinQuantityString(R.plurals.numberOfAdults, adults, context)
    if (teenage > 0) joinPassengers.joinQuantityString(R.plurals.numberOfTeenage, teenage, context)
    if (children > 0) joinPassengers.joinQuantityString(R.plurals.numberOfChildren, children, context)
    if (infants > 0) joinPassengers.joinQuantityString(R.plurals.numberOfInfant, infants, context)

    return joinPassengers.toString()
}
fun StringJoiner.joinQuantityString(id: Int, number: Int, context: Context) {
    with(context.resources) {
        add(getQuantityString(id, number, number))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're using [`Resources.getSystem()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getSystem())

> Return a global shared Resources object **that provides access to only system resources (no application resources)**, is not configured for the current screen (can not use dimension units, does not change based on orientation, etc), and is not affected by Runtime Resource Overlay.

All your `R.whatever` resources are for your *application*, so you need an application `Context` to be able to access them. You can call `Resources.getSystem()` when you don't have a `Context`, but that means you can't access your app stuff with the object you get back. It's not a workaround!

You're using a `data class` which is just a basic data container really, so I wouldn't expect its basic `toString()` implementation to be able to do anything complicated like access its running context. You're better deleting that so it keeps its original implementation (prints the class name and parameter values) and writing your own function you call when you need it to describe itself. That way you can pass in a `Context` (e.g. from the UI component that's going to display it):

```
// you could pass in a Resources object instead, but it's more common to pass a Context
// everywhere instead. Plus this ensures you end up with Resources from an app Context
fun getDescription(context: Context) {
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    with(context.resources) {
        // now 'getQuantityString' is getting called on a Resources object pulled from
        // your app's context, which -does- have access to your app's resources!
        if (adults > 0) sb.append(getQuantityString(R.plurals.numberOfAdults, adults, adults))
        // etc
    }
}
```

Basically, a `Context` gives you access to the environment your code is running in, like the app itself (and all the resources associated with it) and some wider context like the device it's running on, etc. That's why you need to provide one so often, otherwise code is limited to much more general interaction with things.

So if you ever need a `Context` you don't have access to, and you try to just pluck one out of the air, chances are it doesn't have what you need - you have to pass app `Context`s from things that *do* have access to them, to things that *don't*. Usually in constructors or function calls (like here!)